# How is good is Repository Factory together with WSSF

Tags: .net, wcf, wssf

I am working on evaluating few design patterns and frameworks. "Application design should support SOA principles" is the key requirement.
I am looking at frameworks like WSSF and WCSF together. So my first question is how good they are together? Also, I did read at few places that to create a persistance ignorant model, Repository factory can be used along with WSSF.
But I am not sure whether it is supported in  VS 2010 /NEt 4.0 or not. ON code plex I didn't see any support for 2010.
Also I didn't see community and forums speaking too much about it.
My own idea is to create a PI model using ADO.NET entity framework since its supports POCO now. Also, those classes can be used as DataContracts in WSSF.
So to put in one frame I can say WCSF using my services created using WSSF and WSSF will use the entities created by ADO.net entity layer. My Business layer will sit somewhere between WSSF and Ado.net entity layer

Any suggestions how good or bad is my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to not use the Repository Factory for the main reason it was built prior to LINQ and hasn't been updated for the past 2 versions of Visual Studio. There are much easier (and more maintainable) ways to build persistent ignorant models that work with the repository pattern.

Your idea to use EF Code First is much better. However, if you add DataContract attributes to your POCOs, they won't be POCOs anymore IMO.

I know a number of people have used WCSF and WSSF together, but I'm not sure what the caveats are. I wouldn't suspect it to be too difficult unless you want them combined into a single tool. That would be more work and I wouldn't advise it given the roadmap of the underlying technology (GAT/GAX). The p&p team would like VS2010 version of GAT/GAX to be the last version given the advances in VS extensibility.

Comment: and we _do_ look forward to what p&p does next in that space. :-)